# How to make PhpStorm support this syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, phpstorm, webstorm

The below syntax is working just fine

```
import Home from '@/pages/Home'
```

But the following is not: (it throws error about missing of `{` and `from` word like above syntax)

[image]

In `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript` I am using the version
ECMAScript 6 (OSX, PhpStorm v2016.3.2)

The compiler works fine but I'd like to remove the file red error alert.

Is there any plugin which supports this syntax on PhpStorm?

Comment: I'd raise it as a bug with Jetbrains. Doubt there's anything you could do besides disabling that particular inspection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update to the latest version or check the same in [version 2017.2](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program).
This doesn't give me any errors there